# Lost access to Google Compute Windows VM

Tags: google-compute-engine

I was having issues with internet access on a Windows Server 2012 VM, and accidentally disabled the NIC via RDP. Now I can't access the VM.

I tried editing the instance from console; I wanted to add a 2nd NIC, but couldn't do so. I saw something about having to add another "network" but couldn't figure it out.

Is there any way to re-access this VM??

Answer (score 2):

You can re-enable the network interface on the Windows VM using the [Serial port](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/interacting-with-serial-console).

Try these steps:

1. Open the VM instance page from the Google Cloud Platform Console.
2. Click `Edit` on the top bar.
3. Enable the `Enable connecting to serial ports` option and click `Save`.
4. Start the VM if it isn't already running.
5. You will be taken back to the VM's info page and now you can select `Connect to Serial port` dropdown, select `Port 2`.
6. A new window will open up and you will get the Special Administration Console (SAC). Run `cmd` in this serial command prompt.
7. Open up Command prompt channel by pressing `Esc + Tab`.
8. You will have to login as admin on that instance using your admin credentials.
9. In the command prompt, you can enable back your network interface by running these commands:

**Commands:**

```
# List all network adapters - The name is important
netsh interface show interface
# Enable the network adapter
netsh interface set interface "MY_NETWORK_ADAPTER_NAME" admin=enable
```

10. Your instance's network adapter should now be enabled and you should have network access to your VM now.

Comment: (I added step 4, need to start the VM.) After opening the serial console, Port 2 only says `serialport: Connected to acd0-XXXX.us-east1-c.instance-1 port 2 (session ID: XXXX
XXXXX, active connections: 1).` -- but I cannot enter any text; no response.

Comment: I also tried Port 1, and the gcloud shell, but got a bunch of errors `GCEMetadataScripts: ERROR main.go:247: error connecting to metadata server, retrying in 3s, error: Get http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/attributes/?recursive=true&alt=json&timeout_sec=10&last_etag=NONE: dial tcp: lookup metadata.google.internal: getaddrinfow: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found.` ending with `GCEMetadataScripts: No startup scripts to run.`

Comment: Hmm, it is possible `EMS` is not enabled on your VM. Was your VM created recently or long time before? I think the recent GCE Windows VMs have EMS turned on by default. More context on EMS: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/boot-parameters-to-enable-ems-redirection

Comment: I created it 2 days ago.

Comment: @Ze'ev - I'm sorry but I'm out of options here. Your last option might be to just save the persistent disk, create a new Windows VM, attach the persistent disk and copy any files/data you would like to retain and then delete the persistent disk.

Comment: Have a look at https://www.doit.com/restoring-windows-server-access-via-your-google-cloud-serial-console/  This talks you through the process along with the strange syntax of the command terminal

Answer (score 0):

I have observed similar problem on a windows server, where it was not able to resolve Metadata server and auto assigned an APIPA address 169.254.x.x

Performed troubleshooting steps as per Google documentation, also tried with restarting network related services, nothing worked.  Finally reached to this post and tried the following and it got fixed..!

netsh interface set interface name="NAME OF INTERFACE" admin=disabled

netsh interface set interface name="NAME OF INTERFACE" admin=enabled

Not sure why windows behaves as such, Hope this helps